# NSNumber giving wrong value

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I have these values
        int score = 7, answered = 40, skipped = 0, totalRecords = 2;

```
    NSNumber *percentage =[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(score / (answered + skipped)) / totalRecords];
```

It is returning 0.000 instead of 0.0875.
Where is the problem

Comment: You can't divide ints and get floats. You need to cast to floats. i.e. 1/2 = 1 but 1.0/2.0 = 0.5.

Comment: Use float values instead of int! try this NSNumber *percentage =[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(7.0 / (40.0 + 0)) / 2.0];
    NSLog(@"%@",percentage);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your initial value from int to float :

```
float score = 7.0, answered = 40.0, skipped = 0.0, totalRecords = 2.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using integers, and therefore is round to 0.

You need to create them as float:

```
float score = 7.0
```

Or change your values to floats:

```
scoreFloat = (float)score;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using float variables where you really should use integers you can just cast the denominator

```
NSNumber *percentage =[NSNumber numberWithFloat:
            (score / (float)(answered + skipped)) / (float)totalRecords];
```